# Geometrynodes how can i adjust the length of each to the closest length that is divisible by 2m

Tags: geometry-nodes

With geometry nodes how can i convert a mesh into a curve and adjust each edge so it can be divided easily into 2m pieces.

I do not need to keep the exact shape but what i do need is to adjust the length of each edge to the closest length that is divisible by 2m.

So if one edge is 5m it will be shortened or lengthened to either 4m or 6m
and the same for each edge in the curve.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a not so simple algorithm at the base. Do you have any hint about how to calculate it (without geometry nodes)?

Answer (score 3):

And here's an **approaching approach**:

[image]

[image]

Whoops! Above I was approaching the length of $2$, below I'm approaching the nearest multiple of $2$:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice. 'Annealing'  might be the word/searchable term  you're looking for?

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm fine with the "approach". Yes it's a repetition of the word, but it's not [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo). I googled "annealing" and I don't think it fits. With slightly different simulation - no map range, and instead some damping to fight the oscillations, it could be called a "spring approach" (where each spring has length divisible by 2, but they start stretched/squeezed in the simulation; and they don't bend).

Answer (score 2):

> I do not need to keep the exact shape

You can go vertex by vertex and move it closer or further from the previous vertex, depending on which is closer to meeting the 2 m criterion, and maintain the same direction:

[image]

[image]

Notice the `i` starts at `1` - I didn't care to implement equalizing the last edge. This can't be done naively by moving the first point (index 0) in regards to last point, because the edge would be broken when moving the last point. The solution here is to e.g. spawn two spheres, with radius $2$, with centers on second (index #1) and last points, and then move the first point to the nearest intersection of the sphere's surfaces.

Comment: sorry, but ?? all edges multiple of 2, or all but one ?

Comment: @lemon here all but one, it's an incomplete answer. I imagine it will make OP realize the "unexact shape" distorts the original shape too heavily...

Comment: to tell the truth, I've no idea how to make that (for all points), I don't even know if this is possible in general case.

Comment: @lemon it is, I explained one solution (think boolean for example)